# Perl / Awk / Sed - Find and Replace Number & auto-increment

Tags: perl, bash, awk, sed

I am looking for a `perl/awk/sed` command to auto-increment the number in column 7 
Example line in file knownfile.txt:

The file has formatting and 7 columns.

```
today is a great day and it
is also an amazing day tomorrow now
blahblah foo today build number is 5928
```

I want to retain all formatting and simply replace `5928` with `5929` and save file

I tried:

```
awk '/blahblah/{ $7++; print $0 }' filename > tmp && mv tmp filename
```

It increments the number and I think it retains the formatting, but it only prints the edited line to the file.

Comment: Post more lines of sample input and expected output and format both.

Comment: Is the number always in the same place, i.e. at the end of the line?

Comment: Tom, yes the number I want to replace is always at the end of the line.

Comment: FYI any operation you perform on a field (e.g. $7 above) WILL change the formatting because changing a field tells awk to recompile the record ($0) using the OFS value (a single space by default) between fields, so by default all chains of contiguous white space will be replaced by a single blank char. To avoid that, you need to operate on the record as a whole, not any 1 field in the record.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ cat file
today is a great day and it
is also an amazing day tomorrow now
blahblah    foo   today     build number is     5928

$ awk '{sub(/[[:digit:]]+$/,$NF+1)}1' file
today is a great day and it
is also an amazing day tomorrow now
blahblah    foo   today     build number is     5929
```

If that doesn't do what you want then seriously THINK about what sample input and expected output you're posting as that's all we have to go on.

Comment: Nice way of dealing with the formatting issue that mine suffers from (or _would_ suffer from if the input was different). I guess that there should be `/foo/` before the block though.

Comment: idk, I see some answers matching on /foo/ but I don't see any mention of that in the question.

Comment: Good point, that seems to no longer be part of the question. Guess I need to keep up! +1 then for preserving the line format and fulfilling the brief.

Answer (score 6):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -i -pe 's/(\d+)$/1+$1/e' knownfile.txt
```

Comment: i get the message `Modification of a read-only value attempted at -e line 1, <> line 1.`

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing to `perl -i -pe 's/(\d+)$/1+$1/e' knownfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Given that the number is always at the end of the line, you could do this in awk:

```
awk '/foo/{++$NF}1' file
```

where `file` is the file you want to operate on. This simply increments the value of the last column when the line contains the word "foo". The `1` at the end means perform the default action, which is to print the line.

To do this "in-place" on a file, you have to jump through a few hoops:

```
awk '/foo/{++$NF}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Newer versions of `gawk` support in-place editing but this will work everywhere.

Comment: like most languages, awk has a `++` operator so you can write `$NF++` or `++$NF` instead of `$NF = $NF+1`.

Comment: @Ed in the interests of efficiency I'll use the pre-increment version ;) Thanks for pointing that out. I should've done that in the first place.

Comment: Actually, apparently when it saves the data it removes some of the formatting and that is causing an issue.  Any way to keep the spacing / formatting of the line edited?

Comment: @user3642747 It works for the example in your question. If your file is different you should edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @user3642747 I have tried my command against your latest example and it works fine. What is the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: @user3642747 When you increment a field like this, it will change the format to use the default Field Separator (one space) for whole the line.  Look at Eds solution using `sub` to change the field without changing the format of the line.

Comment: Good point @Jotne. Of course, this side-effect isn't apparent due to the fact that the question contains word that are only separated by one space...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -i -pe 's/\d+$/$&+($&>0)/e if /foo/' knownfile.txt
```

Doesn't see `-32` as negative.

Answer (score -1):

This script has no downsides.

```
use Fcntl;
my $fh;
open $fh,"+<$ARGV[0]";
while(<$fh>) {
    if (/foo/) {
        s/(-?\d+)/(($1 > 0) ? ($1+1) : $1)/ge;
    }
    $file .= $_;
}
seek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
print $fh $file;
close $fh;
```

Comment: Some might argue that the script being 12 lines long with cryptic statements is a downside :-).