# Increment (1st) number of each line found in file with one

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, increment

I need to increment the numbers form a file using awk/sed/... .

file:

```
step0=action_a
step1=action_b
step2=action_c
```

output:

```
step1=action_a
step2=action_b
step3=action_c
```

I've tried with:

```
awk '/step/{ $2=$2+1 }' file
```

but the step numbers are not incremented.

Comment: this is very broad. May be best to show your attempts, since this will also narrow down your problem. See [tour] for the basics, welcome!

Comment: hint: `awk '/step/{ print $2 }'`

Comment: In vim, do `:help CTRL+A`

Comment: using: ` awk '/step/{ print $1 }'` returns: step0=action_a
step1=action_b
step2=action_c

Comment: That was a *hint* given by @KarolyHorvath as to why $2 does not refer to what you think it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Perl / Awk / Sed - Find and Replace Number & auto-increment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689603/perl-awk-sed-find-and-replace-number-auto-increment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Ed Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23691919) on a similar question, you could do it like this:

```
$ awk -F'[^[:digit:]]+' '{sub(/[[:digit:]]+/,$2+1)}1' file
step1=action_a
step2=action_b
step3=action_c
```

This replaces the first number (i.e. sequence of digits) with the matched number plus one.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem!

Comment: @EdMorton is it limited to GNU awk, failed on my AIX and fine on my RHEL

Comment: @NeronLeVelu I tested with `gawk --posix` and it appears to work, without  printing any warning about non-posix syntax. Not sure why it doesn't work on AIX.

Comment: here, the `=action_` is removed but number is correctly incremented

Answer (score 1):

awk can do it for sure. however, with vim, your problem could be solved very easily.

```
vim -c "%norm! ^A" file
```

the `^A` you press `Ctrl-V Ctrl-A`

then check the changed text in your vim, if you are satisfied, then press `:wq`  save the file and quit.

If this is not the answer you are looking for, let me know, I would remove the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't solve my issue.